# iOS - How to remove highlighting of selected items in Tab Bar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am customizing the tab bar, and I don't my items to be highlighted with the tint color set to the tab bar item. I wan't the highlight to be just the image that I set for the selectedImage property of the tab bar item.

This is what it looks like now

[image]

I don't want my image to be highlighted with blue. I want it to be just the image that I set.

Please don't tell me about changing tint colors. I am not asking about tint colors here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per UITabBarItem documentation for [init(title:image:selectedImage:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbaritem/1617066-init) initializer:

> By default, the actual unselected and selected images are automatically created from the alpha values in the source images. To prevent system coloring, provide images with 
>   **alwaysOriginal**

So, in your case:

```
let yourTabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: yourTitle, image: yourImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), selectedImage: yourSelectedImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal))
```